# The eXpressApp Framework to Modularize

Tags: asp.net, module, devexpress, xaf

I am R&D Manager in our company. I am looking for good solution to modularize our product. Our company is working on financial and official system. It has many subsystem. We want to combine different subsystem and modularize them, something like Oracle ERP. We want to separate different subsystem and when our customer want special subsystem select them from solution.

Do you think We can use "The eXpressApp Framework"? Please guide me on that

Comment: Will you deploy complete solution and disable(hide) subsytems you don't need or you want to deploy only subsystems you really need? What about domain models, will subsystems domain models depend on each other? Will subsystems have separate databases? Those are the questions you should answer before modularization starts regardless of framework you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know eXpressApp Framework (aka "XAF"), your question cannot be answered with a straight "yes" or "no". XAF has many traits that makes it an awesome platform for a modularized system, but it also comes with some limitations. If you want to use a legacy database, XAF will do a great job in generating persistent classes and a working interface (WinForms and/or ASP.NET) for you. The built-in security-system will let you grant permissions to those classes (and related listviews and detailviews) in a modular way.

However, any logic contained in stored procedures will not be usable automatically and any existing presentation layers will not be easily incorporated in a seamless way.

But since XAF is really customizable, capable, mature and well-supported, I would advice you to give it a shot by downloading and getting to know the evaluation version and contact DevExpress support with the questions you have. Both resources can be found here http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/application_framework/.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for answer, I think disadvantage of XAF is old fashioned design, Layers design is too old, Am I right?

Comment: I don't feel that XAF has an old-fashioned design. If fact, the use of models to create clients for multiple platforms at runtime makes it an agile and future proof framework if you ask me. XAF has evolved a lot since I started using it in 2009, and it even seems to be picking up phase. I don't find a better alternative for creating LOB-applications at the moment.

Comment: Is there any problem If I use XAF? (specially right to left design)

Comment: RTL has been [supported for a while now](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q420833.aspx). A have had some issues from time to time. But they have all been resolved by the support-team (who is really good) and the steady stream of updates. But I cannot guarantee that you won't run into problems, but I would be surprised if they wouldn't be solvable.

Comment: Thank you Fredrik! another question:D I want to use XAF as a framework to design financial system. as you you it consists different subsystem, it is a kind of ERP. We want to use XAF to modularize it. When we change a subsystem we just send a patch to user to run.

Comment: One way to do this is to ship the entire application to the customer, but restrict access to the purchased modules by license keys submitted by you. I'd recommend Click-Once deployment for distributing both the initial installation and regular updates.

Comment: Follow-up on RTL. It just came to my attention that RTL is supported by the ASP.NET-controls, but still seems to be lacking for the WinForms-controls.